# Using Python Requests With Siteminder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib, siteminder

I am having some trouble using Requests to retrieve some data from a webpage. It uses Siteminder and the initial form only has three fields but when I submit it, my password is changed to hex and other fields are added. Can't seem to get it to work at all. I keeps returning an error message.

Any help is appreciated and I apologize for the long post!

Edit: included the two JavaScript functions because they change the data.

Python:

```
from requests import session
with session() as s:

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
    }
    payload = {
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'pw',
        'TARGET': 'https://www.THISSITE.com/pg'
    }

    resp = s.post('https://www.THISSITE.com/THIS/fcc/THISSITE.fcc', headers=headers, data=payload )
    html = resp.text
    print(html)
```

Form:

```
<form
id="login"
method="post"
name="Login"
action="https://www.THISSITE.com/THIS/fcc/THISSITE.fcc">
<input
    type="hidden"
    name="TARGET"
    value="https://www.THISSITE.com/pg"
></input>
<div class="form-group">
    <input
        type="text"
        id="USER"
        name="USER"
        value=""
    ></input>
<div class="form-group">
    <input
        type="password"
        id="PASSWORD"
        name="PASSWORD"
        value=""
    ></input>
</div>
<input
    type="submit"
    name="OK"
    value="Login"
    onclick="submitAuthForm(this.form);"
></input>
```

submitAuthForm(form):

```
function submitAuthForm(form) {

    var strval = form.PASSWORD.value;

    if(!isJson(strval)){
        var info = {};
        info["Password"] = hexEncode(strval);
        form.PASSWORD.value = JSON.stringify(info);
    }
}
```

hexEncode(str):

```
function hexEncode(s){

    var chrsz   = 8;
    var hexcase = 0;

function str2binb (str) {
        var bin = Array();
        var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
        for(var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz) {
            bin[i>>5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (24 - i%32);
        }
        return bin;
    }

    function Utf8Encode(string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    }

    function binb2hex (binarray) {
        var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
        var str = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++) {
            str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((3 - i%4)*8+4)) & 0xF) +
            hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((3 - i%4)*8  )) & 0xF);
        }
        return str;
    }

    s = Utf8Encode(s);
    return binb2hex(str2binb(s));
}
```

Parameters when I submit via webpage:

```
SMENC: UTF-8
SMLOCALE: US-EN
target: https://www.THISSITE.com/pg
smauthreason: 27
smagentname: mR2h1e4BPUPZ5eTpyZckvJXpXO1mE5RpNTYtnh9C8sMfqiHlbrnBjW2SNjbwIRz+
type: 
realmoid: 
smusermsg: 
USER: username
PASSWORD: {"TokenId":"longstringoflettersandnumbersHEX???","Password":""}
```

Comment: Why this line `form.PASSWORD.value = JSON.stringify(info);`?

Comment: @PPJN does my answer solve your issue?

Comment: @mfitzp ill check it tomorrow AM. I am away from my Lc. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hexEncode` function is taking a string and converting to a series of hex representations of the constituent bytes of it's UTF8 encoded representataion. The equivalent in Python would be to encode an input unicode string in UTF-8 and then re-encode the result of that in *hex*, e.g.

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify('d'.encode('utf-8'))
b'64'

>>> binascii.hexlify('¡¢£¤¥'.encode('utf-8'))
b'c2a1c2a2c2a3c2a4c2a5'
```

*Note: in Python 2.7 this would be —*

```
>>> 'd'.encode('utf-8').encode('hex')
'64'

>>> u'¡¢£¤¥'.encode('utf-8').encode('hex')
'c2a1c2a2c2a3c2a4c2a5'
```

If you test that with your example password, it should produce the same output as for the website, with one caveat.

```
hexEncode('d')
"64000000"
```

Notice that the Javascript adds a number of trailing 0's, making the length of the string a multiple of 8. We need to pad the result we have to get the same output.

```
>>> s = binascii.hexlify('d'.encode('utf-8'))
>>> n = len(s)
>>> from math import ceil
>>> next_8_multiple = int(ceil(n/8.0) * 8)
>>> s.ljust(next_8_multiple, b'0')
b'6400000000'
```

We can wrap that up in a complete function:

```
from math import ceil
import binascii

def hex_encode_and_pad(s):
    hex = binascii.hexlify(s.encode('utf-8'))
    n = len(hex)
    next_8_multiple = int(ceil(n/8.0) * 8)
    zeros_to_append = next_8_multiple - n
    return hex.ljust(next_8_multiple, b'0')
```

This now gives the same result as for the Javascript function:

```
>>> hex_encode_and_pad('d')
'64000000'
```

The next step would be to wrap it in a string representation of the JSON. You can either do that by hand-coding the string + just interpolating the token, e.g.

```
value = '{"TokenId":"%s","Password":""}' % token
```

Or by creating the JSON string from a Python dictionary —

```
import json
data = {'TokenId': token, 'Password': ''}
value = json.dumps(data)
```

The complete code based on the example request shown above would be:

```
import binascii
import json
from math import ceil
from requests import session

def hex_encode_and_pad(s):
    hex = binascii.hexlify(s.encode('utf-8'))
    n = len(hex)
    next_8_multiple = int(ceil(n/8.0) * 8)
    zeros_to_append = next_8_multiple - n
    return hex.ljust(next_8_multiple, b'0')

with session() as s:

    password = u'your_password'

    token = hex_encode_and_pad(password)
    data = {'TokenId': token, 'Password': ''}

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
    }
    payload = {
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': json.dumps(data),
        'TARGET': 'https://www.THISSITE.com/pg'
    }

    resp = s.post('https://www.THISSITE.com/THIS/fcc/THISSITE.fcc', headers=headers, data=payload )
    html = resp.text
    print(html)
```

Comment: I get the following error: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Looks like it is thrown on the first line of the hex_encode_and_pad function

Comment: ah, it's because you're using Python3, will rework it

Comment: I apprecitate the effort but I am still unable to log into the page via python:(

Comment: @PPJN can you log in via a browser (use a fake login/pass) and paste what your browser sends? Look at network tab in Chrome Dev tools

Comment: When I put in dummy data, it sends the following. Please note that for the password, I input 'pw' If I emulate this with python, the only difference is that the password shows b'7070000':  {'TARGET': 'webpage.com', 'USER': 'user', 'PASSWORD': {'Password': '70770000'}, 'OK': 'Login'}

Comment: @PPJN is the `b''` ending up in the JSON string? It should not, so if it is that could be a problem. The next things to check would be user agent and/or cookies.

Comment: Had to wrap password dict with json.dumps. Was able to get in!

Comment: Sorry for bringing this back from the dead but it appears that the page now redirects me with authentication. Is there a way to manage that via requests?